# How can I advertise my data in order to be picked up correctly by iOS devices, using BLE

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am dealing with the following situation:

I want to use the BLE advertisement package in order to transmit some data using BLE. I am not using a specific protocol, I am just transmitting a buffer of 31 bytes that has the following structure:

```
0x05, 0x03, 0xXX, 0xXX, 0xXX, 0xXX,// Size 5 List of 16-BIT UUID, number of UUIDs:2
0x18, 0xFF, 0x59, 0x00, //Manufacturer data with length 24, using the Nordic manufacturer identifier
```

and the rest of the data that I want to transmit in the remaining 11 bytes.

I am looking for a way to construct my package in a way that all 31 bytes will be visible from an iOS application.

(I am not developing the iOS application, I just know that there are differences between Android and iOS in the way they read out the data from BLE. My setup works on Android, but it doesn't show all of the transmitted data in iOS)

Answer (score 2):

The raw bytes of the advertising packet is not available on iOS. The data will already have been parsed when `centralManager(_:didDiscover:advertisementData:rssi:)` is called. Your UUIDs should be available in `CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey`, and the manufacturing data (your 11 bytes) should be available in `CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey`.